# Thinkorswim crash in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java

Thinkorswim, a options trading application, continues to crash in Ubuntu. I know it is very sensitive to the java used. I am using the openjdk 7 java in Ubuntu 12.04. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it works for me with the openJDK:

Download the installer from [here](https://mediaserver.thinkorswim.com/installer/InstFiles/thinkorswim_installer.sh). I saved it in `/home/username`

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and:

```
chmod +x /home/username/thinkorswim_installer.sh
cd /home/username
./thinkorswim_installer.sh
echo 'select the installation directory of /home/username/thinkorswim'
echo 'select to install an icon to the desktop'
chmod +x /home/username/Desktop/thinkorswim.desktop
```

That gets you this:
[image]

**I can confirm that it also runs properly with the openjdk version 1.7 when installed in this way.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and had the same problem with its version of openJDK and thinkorswim.  I modified the script "thinkTDA" (which I installed on my desktop) to direct thinkorswim to use a particular JVM, avoiding the need to remove openJDK or your "normal" JVM that may not be working with the program.  To do this, I installed Sun JRE 1.6u31 in a folder in my home directory (outside my search path), then modified line 4 of thinkTDA from

```
# INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=
```

to

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE=/home/[myusername]/myjava/jre1.6.0_31
```

So far it has been stable, and I can use the latest version of Java for other applications as before.  I have not tried this with other JVM's other than Sun 1.7u4, which as reported elsewhere also gave me problems.  I expect that when thinkorswim catches up to the latest JVM's I will be able simply to revert the script to its original form.

Answer (score 0):

aking1012,
TOS support had me remove the OpenJDK and install Sun JRE 1.6.  As a result my java version shows:

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)

But thinkdesktop still crashes so frequently it's unusable.

Did you uninstall Sun JRE and re-install the OpenJDK? Thanks!

Comment: I've only tried the openJDK.  I try to stay away from Sun Java whenever possible.  It launches and seems to run, but I haven't used it much.  It spawns an incredibly large number of threads(looking at htop about 70).  If you have a resource strained system that might be part of it.

Comment: If you installed Sun JRE according to the guide on this site, it should be as uase as update-alternatives<enter>0<enter>

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for java 7 yet.  I have the same issue and they suggested 1.6u32 but that made it very unstable.  I have found 1.6u20 to be the most stable java version for ToS so far.  Please if anyone else knows how to resolve these issues please let us know, I know many are suffering...